# java custom annotation for modifying return value of getter methods

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have some entities in my spring mvc project. Suppose I have three entities A, B and C. A has instance of B and C:

```
public class A {
   ...
   public B b;
   public B getB(){
      return b;
   }
   public void setB(B b){
      this.b = b;
   }


   public C c;
   public C getC(){
      return b;
   }
   public void setC(C c){
      this.c = c;
   }
}
```

I want to modify instances after getting them. For example, I want to set some field of B when I call `getB()` form A. I don't want to do it manually. For example I want to make an annotation for this. Something like this:

```
public class A {
   ...
   public B b;

   @MyCustomAnnotation
   public B getB(){
      return b;
   }
   public void setB(B b){
      this.b = b;
   }


   public C c;

    @MyCustomAnnotation
   public C getC(){
      return b;
   }
   public void setC(C c){
      this.c = c;
   }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Why Spring MVC custom annotation? If I understand correctly, you want to have your own Annotation which you can apply on certain method and perform some logic.

## Create your own annotation as below

Have annotation with `@Target = ElementType.METHOD` as below -

```
@Validation(validator = Validator.MYLOGIC)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{

    int value();

}
```

## Have an enum for your validations as below

```
public enum Validator {

    SOMEOTHERVALIDATION() {
         // Some other validation here
    },
    MYLOGIC() {

        // Have your business logic here

    };
public abstract List<String> validate(Object value,
            Map<String, Object> params, String variable);
}
```

### Have a `ValidationFactory`, use reflection, get the annotation and call specific validation logic

.

```
public class ValidationFactory {

    public void validate(Object object) throws HealthcareValidationException {

        List<String> exceptions = validateObject(object);
        if (exceptions.size() != 0) {
            throw new HealthcareValidationException(exceptions);
        }
    }

    public List<String> validateObject(Object obj) {
        List<String> validationResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                validationResult.addAll(validateField(field, obj));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return validationResult;
    }

    protected static List<String> validateField(Field field, Object obj)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            Validation validationMarker = annotation.annotationType()
                    .getAnnotation(Validation.class);
            if (validationMarker != null) {
                Validator[] validators = validationMarker.validator();

                for (Validator validator : validators) {

                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    String xmlFileld = field.getName();

                    validationExceptions.addAll(validator.validate(
                            field.get(obj), collectParams(annotation),
                            xmlFileld));
                }
            }
        }
        return validationExceptions;
    }
}
```

### Aspect Oriented Programming for Navigation flow

Now you have your custom annotation in place. You can use this annotation in any method. Next, you can use Spring Aspect Oriented Programming to navigate the flow to your annotation logic.

**Example** - Suppose you want to intersect all the methods in a particular package or all the methods whose name start with insert*

```
@Before("execution(* com.learning.application.bo.*.insert*(..))")
    public void validateInsert(JoinPoint joinpoint)
            throws HealthcareValidationException {

        validationFactory = new ValidationFactory();
        Object[] args = joinpoint.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            validationFactory.validate(args[i]);
        }
    }
```

And that's all! Hope this helps.